# Как корректно добавить объект в БД, таблица @ManyToOne, Spring MVC?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, java-ee, jsp

Хочу сделать простенький сайт: список работников, работников можно добавлять и удалять, у каждого работника есть список желаемых подарков.

Есть два класса для связи с БД:

Класс для работника:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

    @Column(name = "birth_day")
    private int birthDay;

    @Column(name = "birth_month")
    private String birthMonth;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "employee") // здесь мы говорим, где искать связь (какое поле в классе Wish)
    private List<Wish> wishes;
```

Класс для пожелания:

```
Entity
@Table(name = "wish")
public class Wish {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "title_of_wish")
    private String titleOfWish;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    private Employee employee;
```

В обоих классах есть пустые конструкторы, геттеры и сеттеры для полей, а в классе работника также есть метод по добавлению желания:

```
public void addWishToEmployee(Wish wish) {
    if (wishes == null) {
        wishes = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    wishes.add(wish);
    wish.setEmployee(this);
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что я не могу настроить добавление желаний так, чтобы они относились к определенному работнику. Либо они добавляются в общий пул, либо возникает ошибка.

Сейчас мой код по добавлению выглядит так:

метод для получения списка пожеланий работников:

```
@RequestMapping("/wishes")
public String showEmployeesWishes(@RequestParam("empId") int empId, Model model) {
    List<Wish> employeeWishes = mainService.getEmployeeWishes(empId);
    model.addAttribute("employeeWishes", employeeWishes);
    return "employees-wishes";
}
```

view для просмотра пожеланий работников:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Employee's Wishes</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Employee's Wishes</h2>
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Go back" onclick="window.location.href='all-employees'">
<br><br>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Wish</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
  </tr>
  <c:forEach var="wish" items="${employeeWishes}">
    <c:url var="deleteButton" value="/deleteWish">
      <c:param name="wishId" value="${wish.id}"/>
    </c:url>

    <c:url var="addButton" value="/addWish">
      <c:param name="empId" value="${wish.employee.id}"/>
  </c:url>

  <tr>
    <td>${wish}</td>
    <td>
      <input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="window.location.href='${deleteButton}'">
    </td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
</table>
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Add New Wish" onclick="window.location.href='${addButton}'">
<br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Метод, который принимает запрос "/addWish":

```
@RequestMapping("/addWish")
public String addWish(@RequestParam("empId") int id, Model model) {
    Employee employee = mainService.getEmployee(id);
    Wish wish = new Wish();
    employee.addWishToEmployee(wish);
    model.addAttribute("wish", wish);

    return "wish-info";
}
```

По моим ожиданиям мы в метод передаем айди работника, для него создаем новое пожелание и перенаправляем пользователя на форму, куда он введет желание, передав туда модель с пожеланием, у которой уже должна быть связь с работником.

На деле происходит так: при нажатии на кнопку "Add Wish" страница просто обновляется и ничего не происходит.

Что заметила: если убрать из метода `addWish` параметры запроса — `@RequestParam("empId")`, то получается зайти на форму для ввода желания. Но тогда я не понимаю, как его связать с конкретным работником

Answer (score 1):

Метод, который принимает запрос "/addWish" не сохраняет данные в БД. Ваш метод  `addWishToEmployee()` всего лишь назначает новому объекту Wish id пользователя и НЕ СОХРАНЯЕТ их. Как следствие, передаваемая туда модель с пожеланием не содержит связь с работником.

```
@RequestMapping("/addWish")
public String addWish(@RequestParam("empId") int id, Model model) 
{
    Employee employee = mainService.getEmployee(id);
    Wish wish = new Wish();
    employee.addWishToEmployee(wish);
    wishService.save(wish);  // Добавленная строка
    model.addAttribute("wish", wish);

    return "wish-info";
}
```

Или

```
@RequestMapping("/addWish")
public String addWish(@RequestParam("empId") int id, Model model) 
{
    Employee employee = mainService.getEmployee(id);
    Wish wish = new Wish();
    employee.addWishToEmployee(wish);
    employeeService.save(employee);  // Добавленная строка
    model.addAttribute("wish", wish);

    return "wish-info";
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CASCADE_TYPE.PERSIST)
private List<Wish> wishes;
```

В последнем блоке кода вам необходимо добавить каскад для того, чтобы связанная сущность Wish также была сохранена в БД при сохранении Employee.

В двусторонней связи, ответственность за сохранение связанных сущностей всегда лежит на плечах стороны Many. Это значит, что при сохранении Wish, связанный Employee также сохранится, но не наоборот.

Comment: Да, метод только перенаправляет на форму для заполнения пожелания. А сохраняет само пожелание метод saveWishToEmployee():     

`@RequestMapping("/saveWish")
    public String saveWishToEmployee(@ModelAttribute("wish") Wish wish) {
        mainService.saveWish(wish);
        return "employees-wishes";
    }`

В него не может попасть атрибут модели с сохраненными данными?

Comment: @Ada насчет этого ничего сказать не могу. Попробуйте сохранить данные перед тем, как их класть в модель.

Comment: @Ada в ново созданной Wish нет своего идентификатора. Нам известен только id работника.

Comment: спасибо, попробую! Правда пока что основная проблема: после нажатия на кнопку "добавить пожелание" следующая страница не открывается

Answer (score 0):

```html
@PostMapping("/addWish")
public String addWish(@RequestParam String employeeInput
                     @RequestParam String wishInput) {
                     
    Employee employee = employeeRepository.findByEmployee(employeeInput);
    // предварительно создав для Employee репозиторий
    // @Repository
    // public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {
    // Employee findByEmployee(String employee);
    // }
    
    Wish wish = new Wish();
    wish.setWish(wishInput);
    wish.setEmployee(employee);
    wishRepository.save(wish);  
    // то же самое - репозиторий для wish, но можно "пустой"
   
    return "wish-info";
}
```

Я делал по другому. Даже по той причине, что мы должны передать в сущность Wish значение этого самого wish. Надо идти со стороны Wish, а не Employee, то есть сохранять сущность Wish, предварительно связав её с Employee. Допустим мы получаем из html страницы 2 параметра (метод Post): employeeInput и wishInput. Тогда маппинг будет выглядеть так (забыл запятую поставить после первого @RequestParam ):